# How can I prevent the navbar content from shifting to the left when I click on a certain page? (website linked below)

Tags: html, css

While clicking on any other page doesn't affect the navbar content, selecting the "important" page shifts all of the navbar text to the left.

Answer (score 0):

it happens because the content is overflowing, so a scrollbar it will appear,

and since your container is `100%` this will happen,

since the width, it will be something like this `(100vw - scrollWidth)`

---

the solution will be to add a `width: 100vw;` to all elements that need to be having all width of the device

> since you didn't give the code, I can't modify and send you the solution code. (but I suppose it will be something like `ul { width: 100vw; }`